# Accessing WCF's events from svc.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service in a project.
I have a web project inside which i have my svc & svc.cs file.

My WCF service was already written in  different project, so i just deleted all my svc and svc.cs code and provided markup inside my svc file to refer to my WCF service.

I have successfully hosted my svc file and my WCF functions receive calls from the clients.
All is fine uptill here.

Now, my WCF code also has some events which it raises. I expect my svc file should provide handler to these events. So I provided these handlers inside constructor in my svc.cs file. However, the constructor inside my svc.cs file just does not hit and as a result the events raised by my WCF service are not being handled (inside my svc.cs file).

What should i take care of?

The reason i have to do it this way is because my WCF service is being hosted inside a console application as well as a windows service. These hosts too provide for handlers for events inside the WCF which get successfully hit. How should i do it by hosting my WCF inside iis?

my Servic1.svc is -

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyServiceNameSpace.MyService" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs"%>
```

my Service1.svc.cs is

```
public class Service1
{
  static Service1()
  {
    //EventHandler1 is of type Func<string, string>
    MyService.EventHandler1 = Service1_EventHandler1;
  }
  static string Service1_EventHandler1(string param1)
  {
    //event handling code
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show an excerpt of your constructor, the events and the handler

Comment: code added in the main question.. pls check

Comment: There is something strange in your design. WCF services are for catching calls from clients. Why do want do catch an event in your WCF service ? The constructor of the service is called only if there is a call to the web service

Comment: My WCF service library was originally calling a third party dll function. However, it was observed that this call did not go through (and no errors too).
When this call was given from a console application project, the call went through. This was confirmed from a phone call over which the third party dll functionality is wrapped.
So what i had to do, raise events from my Service library, handle them inside a windows service and call the third party dll function from within windows service.
Now, i want to reuse this Service library from within IIS hosted project in similar architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the **constructor of the service to be called before the first web service call**, provide a **ServiceHostFactory** that controls when service is instanciated :

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="C#" 
               Debug="true" 
               Service="MyServiceNameSpace.MyService" 
               CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs"
               Factory="MyNS.MyServiceHostFactory
               %>
```

Then implement the factory :

```
public class MyServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory{
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Service instanciated before first web service call 
 // and making subscription to the event
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////
 private IService1 serviceInstance = new Service1();
 protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(
                                    Type serviceType, 
                                    Uri[] baseAddresses ) {
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceInstance);
    // add the endpoints …
    return host;
 }
}
```

In the previous sample it is a singleton service.
But **ServiceHostFactory** can also be used to instanciate a different service every time.

Regards

Comment: Thank you Emmanuel, although, i didn't use the code inside the CreateServiceHost, however, i learnt from this that i can create such ServiceFactory.. my configurations are all inside my config file so i won't bother about writing them in here.. just fyi.. all i m doing inside my CreateServiceHost function is - initiating my ServiceHost as new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses) and then returning it.. just before returning, i make a dummy object of my Host class so that it can provide all the event handling.. my test function ran successfully.. i can follow from there